# Массивы FASM можно ли добавлять строки

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Всем привет! у меня есть массив `arr dw 1,2,3,4,'text'` является ли правильным то, что я добавил строку к элементу массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, код не скомпилируется (ошибка "error: value out of range.") Фактически fasm будет пытаться уместить строку размером в 4 байта (в данном случае 1 байт = 1 символу) в элемент массива размером word (т.е. 2 байта, размер элемента задается в данном случае директивой dw - "define word"). А вот если разбить строку на куски по 2 байта, например так:

```
arr dw 'te', 'xt'
```

то код скомпилируется. Но на практике лучше не смешивать строки и числа в одном массиве, а хранить строки в байтовых (`db`) или юникодных (`du`, utf-16) массивах.